# How to keep track of animation state

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

**Context**
I have two text fields in a stack view. When either is tapped, I need them both to animate upward simultaneously.

When you switch from one textfield to the next, I want them both to stay in place. It should only animate back down when the keyboard gets dismissed.

Since both text fields have their own delegate, clicking from one to the next triggers the downward animation slightly causing a little jump. The jump is the bug I want removed.

**What I have tried:**
I created a Bool that is supposed to keep track if an animation has occurred already. However changing its state with self attached, as well as triggering it with a method doesn't seem to work.

```
func didAnimate() {
    self.isAnimated = true
    print("Didanimate result:" + String(isAnimated))
}

func animateUp() {
    // moves views up to avoid keyboard
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                   delay: 0,
                   options: .curveEaseOut,
                   animations: {
                    self.textFieldsY.constant += 200
                    //print("~~~~~~~~~")
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    self.didAnimate()
                    print(self.isAnimated)
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        self.isAnimated = true
    })
}

func animateDown() {
    // moves views down after keyboard leaves
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                   delay: 0,
                   options: .curveEaseOut,
                   animations: {
                    self.textFieldsY.constant -= 200
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    self.isAnimated = false
    }, completion: nil)
}

//MARK:- Text Field delegate
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if (keyBoardIsVisible) {
        // no need to animate anything
    } else {
        self.animateUp()
        self.keyBoardIsVisible = true
    }
    print("initial animate result:" + String((isAnimated)))

}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if(keyBoardIsVisible) {
    animateDown()
        self.keyBoardIsVisible = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Copy and paste the actual text into your question. Images are harder to read, can't be searched, and the code can't be referenced or copied.

Comment: Don't post a screen shot of your image.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and `textFieldDidEndEditing` to handle keyboard animation. Because whenever you switch to second textfield `textFieldDidEndEditing` will get called.

I think better approach will be to use local notification to handle this scenario using these two notifications in Swift 3:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourController.keyboardWillShow(sender:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourController.keyboardWillHide(sender:)),name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func animateUp() {
  // moves views up to avoid keyboard
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                 delay: 0,
                 options: .curveEaseOut,
                 animations: {
                  self.textFieldsY.constant += 200
                  //print("~~~~~~~~~")
                  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                  print(self.isAnimated)
  }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
  })
}

func animateDown() {
  // moves views down after keyboard leaves
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1,
                   delay: 0,
                   options: .curveEaseOut,
                   animations: {
                    self.textFieldsY.constant -= 200
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}


func keyboardWillShow (notification: NSNotification) {
  if (keyBoardIsVisible) {
    return
  } else {
      self.animateUp()
      self.keyBoardIsVisible = true
  }
  print("initial animate result:" + String((isAnimated)))

}

func keyboardWillHide (notification: NSNotification) {
  if(keyBoardIsVisible) {
    animateDown()
    self.keyBoardIsVisible = false
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not understanding the benefit of using the notification center in this case.

Comment: If I am not using the delegates as triggers, how will i know where to put these notifications?